# EXTERNAL TABLE with CSV is not getting autorefreshed

Tags: hive, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have created an external table using CSV as below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE OpenCSVSerde_CSV (
  id STRING COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  name STRING COMMENT 'from deserializer'
  )
USING CSV
LOCATION 'abfss://test@xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/csvtabletest';
```

When I add a new file to the path abfss://test@xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/csvtabletest, table is not getting refreshed, i have to manually do a REFRESH TABLE OpenCSVSerde_CSV.
I tried to set the spark config at the cluster level, but it did not help either.

```
spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled false
```

Is there a way I could make the data refresh automatic?

Answer (score 2):

By default, that doesn't automatically refresh the table. So, you need to run `REFRESH TABLE OpenCSVSerde_CSV` after adding new files in the location.

But, to make this query run automatic you follow below ways.

1. Setting the `File Arrival` trigger to the notebook. Whenever the file is added it will trigger the notebook to run the above query. You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/jobs/file-arrival-triggers) documentation for it.
2. Also you can add schedule to run notebook for certain interval of time based on how frequent your files are added.

You can follow below steps for second option using schedule.

**Goto Workflows** > **Jobs**  > **Create Job**

Next add the required details.

[image]

1. **Task name**: Give a name to task
2. **Type**:  `Notebook`
3. **Source**: `Workspace`
4. **Path** Give the path to the notebook having refresh table query
5. **Cluster**: select the cluster to run

And click on create.
After creating you will get the interface as below.

[image]

There you click on **Add schedule**, then select
**Trigger Type** as `Scheduled` and **Schedule** for every 5 minutes. This you can change according to how frequently your files will be added, I've given for every 5 mins.
And click on save.

[image]

Below are the files in storage account and records from select query.

[image]

and

[image]

Now adding new csv file `newuser.csv`.
It will refresh the table for every 5 minutes and gets data added in this 5 minute interval.

Output:

[image]

and

[image]